# "disk drive for /dev/shm is not ready yet" at boot

Tags: 11.10, boot, kernel, mount, ppa

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 i386 on a laptop. I recently upgraded linux generic kernel to 3.0.0-14 with a PPA (eugensan/boiler): I actually was looking to install just one piece of software ("unison"), but I got carried away and installed all the updates the PPA was providing, including the kernel  (silly of me, I know... ,I'll sure think twice next time)

After the upgrade, at boot time the system complains with:

> ```
> disk drive for /run/shm is not ready yet or not present"
> ```

and a similar message for `/run/tmp`

I can still boot by opting to skip these filesystems.  However Chrome will not work now unless I enter the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /run/shm
chmod 1777 /dev/shm
```

I reverted back to the previous kernel (3.0.0-13), removed the PPA and searched the web quite extensively, but to no avail.

I also checked `/etc/fstab` and this is what I have:

```
proc         /proc    proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1    /        ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1
UUID=c79075aa-eb63-43bc-ab8f-12eb26bfcfbd none  swap    sw     0       0
```

If anybody has any suggestion on how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Mountall package in eugenesan ppa is broken. Just comment these sources.list lines, and run

```
 sudo aptitude install mountall=2.31
```

After that everything should be ok.